# wrapping blocks in jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have two jinja2 templates where the second extends the first one:

```
<h1>Some title</h1>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

and

```
{% block content %}
  content
{% endblock %}
```

Now I want to be able to insert a variable number of "wrappers" between those two templates where the second one extends the wrapper (which extends the next wrapper)* which extends the first template. A wrapper could look like this:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I would expect this to result in the following rendered HTML:

```
<h1>Some title</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  content
</div>
```

Unfortunately the wrapper template from above is not valid in jinja2 because blocks simply don't work like this. So is there any way to do what I want to do in jinja2? If not: Are there any other template engines that are capable of it?

(Note that renaming the inner block won't do because I need to be able to add a *variable* number of wrappers.)

Comment: You need to give your blocks unique names.

Comment: I know that. My question is not *why* this does not work, but *how* I could make it work. And unique names are not a solution as already explained in the question.

Comment: How do you control the variable number of wrappers?

Comment: There is a list of template paths and the first line in each template says `{% extends templates.pop() %}`.

Comment: I don't believe that is related. Somewhere you must have a control structure, either an `if` or a `for`, that wraps around one or more `{% block content %}`. If that isn't the case, I suspect your problem can be solved with either unique block names or calls to `{{ super() }}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    {{ super() }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

From [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#super-blocks):

> It’s possible to render the contents of the parent block by calling super. This gives back the results of the parent block:

Comment: This does actually work. But the extension is in the opposite direction of what I expected: The wrapper is at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your blocks unique names. Your problem is obviously a result of the double-use of the `content` block.